# Can Time Machine backup Windows running on Parallels

Tags: mac, time-machine, parallels

Ive got Time Machine running on my macbook and that covers the backup of almost everything, but there are also a few programs that i have to run on windows that i use parallels for.

Can Time Machine backup the windows parallels files at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only when the Windows VM is NOT running.

When the VM runs the files are in use and in such a way that a snapshot-backup (which is what Time Machine does with "open" files) is useless.
You will get a backup of the VM's files but they will 99 of a 100 times not be usable to recover the VM.

(Same is true for VM's in VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion too.)

Comment: When you say 'but it will 99 of a 100 times not be usable to recover' are you referring to all the backups or backups made when then VM is running ?

Comment: The backup of the VM made when the VM was running. Will edit to clarify. Should not write this sort of thing past midnight.